# Менять картинку радиокнопками

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Всем привет! Надеюсь здесь мне кто нибудь сможет подсказать.
Есть 2 радиокнопки

```
<input type="radio" name="change" value="1" checked> 
<input type="radio" name="change" value="2">
```

И есть еще вот такой код

```
<div class="main-img">
    <a href="<?php the_field('img_product_1'); ?>">
        <img src="<?php the_field('img_product_1'); ?>"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Первая радиокнопка выбрана и все на своих местах, а вот когда выбираешь вторую радиокнопку я хочу что бы картинка менялась например на

```
<a href="<?php the_field('img_product_2'); ?>">
        <img src="<?php the_field('img_product_2'); ?>"/>
</a>
```

Ну и конечно же когда выбираешь первую радиокнопку опять появлялась первая картинка.

Надеюсь более менее понятно объяснил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так: ( http://jsfiddle.net/wL4q2/1/ ):

```
<input class="img-select" type="radio" name="change" value="1" data-img="<?php the_field('img_product_1'); ?>" checked />

<input class="img-select" type="radio" name="change" value="2" data-img="<?php the_field('img_product_2'); ?>" />

<div class="main-img">
    <a href="<?php the_field('img_product_1'); ?>">
        <img src="<?php the_field('img_product_1'); ?>"/>
    </a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $imgChanger = $('.img-select');
    if ($imgChanger.length) {
        var $imgCnt = $('.main-img');
        $imgChanger.change(function(){
            var data = $(this).data('img');
            if (data) {
                $imgCnt.find('a').attr('href',data);
                $imgCnt.find('img').attr('src',data);
            }
        });
    }

});
</script>
```

Если value не нужно у радио-баттона можно использовать его вместо data-атрибута

Comment: Спасибо огромное, то что нужно. А что бы использовать больше радиобоксов просто добавлять их и все так же будет работать?

Comment: Да именно так, используйте любое количество "радио-баттонов".